# injective tensor norms for real tensors

Tags: tensor-products, operator-norms, rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces

If $A$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes\mathbb{R}^n \otimes\mathbb{R}^n$, then define its [injective tensor norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product) to be
$$\|A\|_{\rm inj} := \max_{x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}^n, \|x\|=\|y\|=\|z\|=1} 
|\langle A, x\otimes y\otimes z\rangle|.$$
Here the norm on vectors is the usual Euclidean norm.

I have two questions.

1. Does this norm change if x,y,z can be taken to arbitrary *complex* unit vectors?
2. What if $A$ is symmetric under exchange of the first two positions?  That is,
   $\langle A, x\otimes y\otimes z\rangle = \langle A, y\otimes x\otimes z\rangle$ for all $x,y,z$.

edit: My motivation for this question is related to the paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4484

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the $$ equation to work.

Comment: Fixed your LaTeX and added the "banach-spaces" tag

Comment: As clarification: what exactly is the second question? Is it whether the norm changes if $A$ is symmetric in two factors and the vectors are allowed to be complex (as in the first question)?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [this paper](http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/pdf/RRACEFN_2000_94_04_05.pdf), which gives an example in which the real and complex version of the norm *are* different.  The tensor in this example is also symmetric, which provides an example for part 2 as well.